# Background picture doesn't show fully on browser and even worst on mobile

Tags: css, image, background, responsive

1. My main background image adapts to screen resolution but the picture gets cut off in the process and as a result, you don't see the full picture.
2. The picture is even worst on mobile/tablet (even more cut off)

How do you show the full picture and adapt it to every browser/mobile/tablet for a full screen res?

I'm not even sure where to modify the coding.

Could this code be the problem?

```css
 * 28.0 Section
 */

.magee-section {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -ms-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.fullheight {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.verticlemiddle {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.magee-section.verticlemiddle .container,
.magee-section.verticlemiddle .container-fullwidth {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.magee-section .background-media,
.magee-section .background-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.magee-section .background-media {
}

.magee-section .background-overlay {
}

.magee-section .container,
.magee-section .container-fullwidth {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. No image is going to perfectly fill every screen aspect ratio without some distortion or cropping. What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I have a website (which is a one pager website) and I want to have a full screen background for the <section 1>... now I do have a full screen image but it seems like the coding made a zoom in in order to make it fit... on the browser it ain't too bad of a zoom, but on a mobile, it get's pretty bad... maybe ill have to change the .php file of "section 1"? I'm clueless right now... website is: [www.landrycarts.com] if you try to open it on a mobile, you'll see what I mean

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
    background: url("a.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

and do not forget to add the viewport in the HEAD:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/668j8xr8/